# how to parse the binary format string in Python

Tags: python

I have a gzipped data in binary format and I read it using python by:

```
file = gzip.open('test.gz','r')
line = file.readline()
```

then the line is in following format:

```
'\xd7\xa3p]\x81@tB  Z\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc1g\xef\xa3\x8aE\x13AAPL\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8Z\x81@tS  \n'
```

What I know is for eachline, the first byte should be a 1 byte string, second byte is a string, third byte is an integer. So how should I deal with binary format string to decode the information which I want? Thanks!

Comment: It  is not binary - it is unicode text. Example just do `print x.encode('utf-8')` where `x = u'\xd7\xa3p]\x81@tB  Z\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc1g\xef\xa3\x8aE\x13AAPL\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8Z\x81@tS  \n'`

Comment: Hi, I tried as you said, but I got one exception is: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: did you notice the `u` around the string, which denotes it as a unicode, and not string

Comment: Hi, I still not figure out. The variable line I see is a string and don't have u around it. How should I convert the variable line to your format?

Comment: @user2970089 what is the data inside the file, or where do you get it from?

Comment: @aseeon I don't know.It is just one of our python programming homework. But I am having trouble how to read binary data from gzip file and get the useful information which I mentioned at the question part.

Comment: @user2970089 you need to use [struct module (docs link)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) from standard library to define the struct (first byte string, second byte string and so on) and unpack the line you got with it. You can find some exmaples [Here](http://pymotw.com/2/struct/)